# How to create an Observable in Android?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

What I want to do is to create a simple in-memory cache just to try Observables out. However I got stuck because I don't understand how to create an observable. This is the code I have gotten so far:

```
public class MovieCache {
    MovieWrapper movieWrapper;

    public Observable<MovieWrapper> getMovies() {
       //How to create and return an Observable<MovieWrapper> here?
    }

    public void setCache(MovieWrapper wrapper) {
        movieWrapper = wrapper;
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        movieWrapper = null;
    }
}
```

In the `getMovies()` method I want to create an Observable and return my local field movieWrapper to the subscriber. How can I do this? I tried with using `new Observable.just(movieWrapper)` but it results in a null exception.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://blog.danlew.net/2015/07/23/deferring-observable-code-until-subscription-in-rxjava/) as it does exactly what you are looking for. Basically you use `defer()` to make sure you always get the latest version of your cached object:

```
public class MovieCache {
    MovieWrapper movieWrapper;

    public Observable<MovieWrapper> getMovies() {  
        return Observable.defer(new Func0<Observable<MovieWrapper>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<MovieWrapper> call() {
                return Observable.just(movieWrapper);
            }
        });
    }

    public void setCache(MovieWrapper wrapper) {
        movieWrapper = wrapper;
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        movieWrapper = null;
    }
}
```

`defer()` makes sure that you will get the object upon *subscription* to the `Observable` not on *creation*.

Note however that, according to the author of the post:

> The only downside to defer() is that it creates a new Observable each
>   time you get a subscriber. create() can use the same function for each
>   subscriber, so it's more efficient. As always, measure performance and
>   optimize if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

As already said, accepted answer has downside

> it creates a new Observable each time you get a subscriber

But it is not the only one.

- Consumer won't receive any value if he calls `getMovies().subscribe(...)` before `setCache(...)` is called.
- Consumer should resubscribe if he want to receive any updates (let's say `setCache()` can be called multiple times.

Of course all of them can be irrelevant in your scenario. I just want to show you another way (I'm sure there are many more).
You can use `BehaviorSubject` in order to eliminate all these disadvantages.

```
public class MovieCache {
    private BehaviorSubject<MovieWrapper> mMovieCache = BehaviorSubject.create();

    public void setCache(MovieWrapper wrapper) {
        mMovieCache.onNext(wrapper);
    }

    public Observable<MovieWrapper> getMovieObservable() {
        //use this if consumer want to receive all updates
        return mMovieCache.asObservable();
    }

    public MovieWrapper getMovie() {
        //use this if consumer want to get only current value
        //and not interested in updates
        return mMovieCache.getValue();
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        //CAUTION consumer should be ready to receive null value
        mMovieCache.onNext(null);
        //another way is to call mMovieCache.onCompleted();
        //in this case consumer should be ready to resubcribe
    }

    public static class MovieWrapper {}

}
```

Take a look at [BehaviorSubject marble diagram](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/subjects/BehaviorSubject.html).